# Symbolic function based on existing function ignores conditions inside this existing function

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, symbolic-math

I am trying to create a symbolic function based on an existing function `zz`.

Here is mu `zz.m` file:

```
function p = zz(b)
    b(b==0) = 1;
    p = b;
end
```

Here is the script to create a symbolic function `yy`:

```
syms a
yy = symfun(zz(a), a);
```

Then I have the expected result with `zz`(the condition is respected) when I do in the console:

```
>> zz(0)

ans =

     1
```

But when I used the created symbolic function `yy`, I don't have the expected result:

```
>> yy(0)

ans =

0
```

I suspect there might be explicated somewhere that formulas for symbolic functions cannot have conditions, but I cannot find a reference.

I've been looking at [`symbolic`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.htm), [`sym`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html), [`syms`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) documentations and tried to look some references online, but I didn't find any references (maybe I had the wrong keywords...).

Comment: You should use [piecewise](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html) introduced in matlab 2016b.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you need symbolic function instead of just using function call?

Comment: @hazeiio my initial code is way more complex. I reduced it to be [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the difference between zz(0) and yy(0) that you need, so I can maybe provide different solution.

Comment: @hazeiio. Thanks for your concern, but my point is to understand this specific behaviour with the symbolic concept.

Comment: This behavior is quite straightforward. You can place a single `disp` inside your `zz` function, and you will see that it gets called when you declare what `yy` is, meaning it tries to evaluate `zz(a)` where `a` is symbolic variable, and it returns 0. The function `zz` is not called when you use `yy(0)`, rather it only uses precomputed value, which is symbolic variable itself, meaning: `zz(a)` is same is `a` alone.

Comment: Edit to previous comment as I have just noticed the mistake: '...is symbolic variable, and it returns `a`.'

Comment: @hazeiio, I think you had some interesting thoughts so feel free to write an answer.